# SEO pages not generating dynamic in sitemap.xml

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am generating sitemap.xml, it's generated 17 files which has links on the site means pages are either in header or footer or interlinking but I have 50 SEO pages which is not generating.

We don't have any links on the site it means (header, footer and interlinking) any where it is in View/Pages folder and method is in PagesController. I want to dynamic generate 50 SEO pages in sitemap.xml. How it will work?

I am doing through Generator.zip folder.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
public function seo_sitemap()
{
    $this->autoRender=false;
    $data = $this->Page->find('all');
    if(!empty($data))
    {
      $writer = new XMLWriter();
      $writer->openURI(WWW_ROOT.'/seo_pages_sitemap.xml');
      $writer->startDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
      $writer->setIndent(4);
      $writer->startElement('urlset');
      $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
      $writer->writeAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
      $writer->writeAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');

      foreach ($data as $list)
      {

        $urls = SITEURL."/".$list['Page']['url'].".html";
        $lin=utf8_encode($urls);
        $url_date = date(DATE_W3C, strtotime($list['Page']['created']));
        $writer->startElement('url');
        $writer->writeElement('loc', $lin);
        $writer->writeElement('lastmod',trim($url_date));
        $writer->writeElement('changefreq', 'always');
        $writer->writeElement('priority', '0.8');
        $writer->endElement();

      }

        $writer->endElement();
        $writer->endDocument();
        echo SITEURL.'sitemap.xml created<br>';

    }


}
```

Comment: hey but for this I think I need to create a table.Because I do not have any model as Page. because it is a static page. I didn't save URL in table too